# Tun terminal command with Java method

Tags: java

I have a checking `check.jar`,
and a modeling file example `file.mso`.
To start checking I must use a terminal and I type the command:

```
java -jar check.jar
load file.mso  ;;
```

It's two line on the terminal generates a file on my current directory
I create an application to use my file `check.jar`.
My application can manage files create, delete a file type ... but I block manager on a function to launch the two control lines on my device is using a javascript functionto explain the situation,
on my application I can create file `file.mso`

Now to start checking, I right click and choose I start checking
I am trying to write this function but I have no idea how to do
my function code is as follows

```
LancerVeritaf function (o, CurDir, gsitem) {

}
```

I want to write this function, to run `java -jar check.jar` and `load my file I select with a right click ;;`

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wrote the code in the jar file, just change the main() in the Main-Class declared in your manifest to process arguments passed in via argc and argv[]

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if ( argc >= 2 )
    {
        String filename = argv[1];
        // process the filename here

}
```